# R debugging nested ifelse() statement

Tags: r, optimization

When I run this code line by line it works, but if I run the whole block of code it gives me an error.
what I'm trying to do here is
ifelse(< cond >,{yes; ifelse(< cond >,{yes,no})}, no)

```
ifelse(myfunct(R) >= myfunct(worst_point), 
 {IC <- C - 0.5 * (R - C); ifelse(myfunct(IC) < myfunct(worst_point), {points[[which.max(result)]] <- IC},
  for (i in 2:(n+1)) {points[[i]] <- best_point + 0.5 * (points[[i]] - best_point)})},
  for (i in 2:(n+1)) {points[[i]] <- best_point + 0.5 * (points[[i]] - best_point)})
```

but its giving me an error:

```
Error in ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test &  : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Part where its giving me an error is for-loops inside ifelse() statement and I don't know why, could someone help me understand this error message?

Comment: It looks like you want to use a real `if`-`else` block. See this page for what looks like a reasonable introduction to the concept: https://www.programiz.com/r-programming/if-else-statement

Comment: @NickNimchuk hey some how using real if-else block worked,.. I used ifelse() because previously real if-else block didn't chain through multiple nested if statements but maybe I made a mistake.. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was assignment in the `yes` and `no` arguments of `ifelse()`. That function is meant to return a value of the same shape as its `test` argument. Here I tried to rewrite it using `if()` and `else` statements, and based on your comment you already did that successfully.

```
if(myfunct(R) >= myfunct(worst_point)) {
  IC <- C - 0.5 * (R - C)
  if(myfunct(IC) < myfunct(worst_point)) {
    points[[which.max(result)]] <- IC
    }else{for (i in 2:(n+1)) {
                points[[i]] <- best_point + 0.5 * (points[[i]] - best_point)
                } 
    }
  }else{for (i in 2:(n+1)) {
    points[[i]] <- best_point + 0.5 * (points[[i]] - best_point)}}
```